# Typo3 plugin Typoscript contants javascript add file

Tags: php, include, typo3, typoscript, typo3-4.5

I'm trying to add a Javascript file to a Typo3 plugin that a company has built for me.

The file main.js(/public_html/typo3conf/etc/intranetapi/Resources/Public/Javascript/main.js) is now being included. I've been searching through the code and found the following:

**public_html/typo3conf/etc/intranetapi/Configuration/TypoScript/contants.txt**

```
plugin.tx_intranetapi {
    settings {
        js {
            # cat=plugin.tx_intranetapi_js/javascript; type=string; label=Javascript file 1
            file1 = EXT:intranetapi/Resources/Public/Javascript/main.js     
        }
    }
}
```

**public_html/typo3conf/etc/intranetapi/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt**

```
plugin.tx_intranetapi {
    settings {
        js {
            file1 = {$plugin.intranetapi.settings.js.file1}
        }
    }
}

page.includeJSFooterlibs.intranetapi = {$plugin.tx_intranetapi.settings.js.file1}
```

The file main.js is included the way it should, but now I'd like to add another javascript file called intranetApi.js.

I thought I could do that this way:
**public_html/typo3conf/etc/intranetapi/Configuration/TypoScript/contants.txt**

```
plugin.tx_intranetapi {
    settings {
        js {
            # cat=plugin.tx_intranetapi_js/javascript; type=string; label=Javascript file 1
            file1 = EXT:intranetapi/Resources/Public/Javascript/main.js 

            # cat=plugin.tx_intranetapi_js/javascript; type=string; label=Javascript file 2
            file1 = EXT:intranetapi/Resources/Public/Javascript/intranetApi.js      
        }
    }
}
```

**public_html/typo3conf/etc/intranetapi/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt**

```
plugin.tx_intranetapi {
    settings {
        js {
            file1 = {$plugin.intranetapi.settings.js.file1}
            file2 = {$plugin.intranetapi.settings.js.file2}
        }
    }
}

page.includeJSFooterlibs.intranetapi = {$plugin.tx_intranetapi.settings.js.file1}
page.includeJSFooterlibs.intranetapi = {$plugin.tx_intranetapi.settings.js.file2}
```

After the code changes above, I cleared all Typo3 cache by clicking on the lightening icon at the top of the page. But unfortunatly it isin't working.

I personally think it has something to do with page.includeJSFooterlibs.intranetapi = {$plugin.tx_intranetapi.settings.js.file2} where I'm overwriting the old config I think.
I also tried `page.includeJSFooterlibs.intranetapi = {$plugin.tx_intranetapi.settings.js.file1, $plugin.tx_intranetapi.settings.js.file2}` but that doesn't work either...

I'm quite new to Typo3 and I can't find any other information about this sort of problems. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In **public_html/typo3conf/etc/intranetapi/Configuration/TypoScript/contants.txt** you have file1 two times, this overrides the first javascript file (main.js).

For the second file you can use another name in the TypoScript setup, so instead **intranetapi** two times, **intranetapi** and (eg) **intranetapi2**.

Comment: Also your once your constant ``plugins.**tx_**intranetapi`` and in your setup you use it as ``plugins.intranetapi``. This wont work.